# Show that $\int_0^{\infty}\|f(s)\|_E\:{\rm d}s<\infty$ implies $\frac1t\int_0^tsf(s)\:{\rm d}s\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $f:[0,\infty)\to E$ be continuous. Assume $$\int_0^\infty\|f(s)\|_E\:{\rm d}s<\infty\tag1.$$ How can we conclude that $$\frac1t\int_0^tsf(s)\:{\rm d}s\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}0\tag2$$

We can clearly write $$\frac1t\int_0^tsf(s)\:{\rm d}s=\frac1t\int_0^t\int_r^tf(s)\:{\rm d}s\:{\rm d}r\tag3$$ for all $t>0$, but how can we conclude from this and $(1)$?

Comment: the first statement is not necessary as $f$ is continuous so $\int_{0}^t \|f(s)\|\,d s<\infty $ always for any $t$, maybe you wanted to say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\|f(s)\|\,d s<\infty $?

Comment: @Masacroso I'm sorry, $t$ should be $\infty$ in $(1)$.

Comment: I guess that you mean  $\int_{0}^{+\infty}||f(s)||ds<+\infty$ in the assumption! Besides you don't use norm in the second integral. Do you mean $f(s)$ is a real number? In that case you don't need a norm in the first integral but an absolute value. Or that the integral is a vector integral? Because taking $E$ as an arbitrary Banach space we cannot define what the second integral really means! Please clarify!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos I don't see how $(1)$ is different from $\int_{0}^{+\infty}||f(s)||ds<+\infty$. Regarding the "second" integral (I guess you mean the one in $(2)$): It is a Bochner integral and the convergence is in $E$.

Comment: OK that makes it clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion holds by applying DCT to $\int_0^{\infty} \frac  s  t \chi_{(0,t)} (s) \|f(s)\|
ds$. Note that $0 \leq \frac  s  t \chi_{(0,t)} (s)\|f(s)\| \leq \frac s  t \|f(s)\|\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ for each $s$ and $0 \leq \frac  s  t \chi_{(0,t)} (s)\|f(s)\|\leq \|f(s)\|$ which is integrable.

Comment: I'm not sure about why received a downvote, but won't your argument imply that $f$ has $0$ norm?

Comment: I think that the correct assumption is lim of the integral<$+\infty$

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo in $(1)$. $t$ should actually be $\infty$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have added some details for application of DCT.